# Azure Streaming Analytics Jobs scaling SU

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I'm running into an issue I can't fix:

I created a Azure Streaming Analytics Jobs, that sometime run into this error:

```
Resource usage is over the capacity for one or more of the query steps. 
Event processing may be delayed or stop making progress. This may be a 
result of large window in your query, large events in your input, large out 
of order tolerance window, or a combination of the above. Please try to 
partition your query, or break down your query to more steps, and add 
Streaming Unit resources from the Scale tab to avoid such condition., :
```

So I decided to scale up the SU. I stopped the job, I open the scale pane and the input box keep grey. I can't change the SU value, no error message.

What can I do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the SU scale you need admin/owner role on the Azure Stream Analytics job.
Sorry for the inconvenience, we are changing the user experience in order  to make this more explicit.
Let me know if it works for you after you get the admin role.
Thanks.,
JS